# Prevent Elements Below pop-up from responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have a div which I have designed to pop-up and cover my screen. The problem is, when I click on an empty space within this pop-up, the elements below this pop-up respond to these clicks. The effects after that, I am accidentally executing click events from these elements below this div which I do not want.

Can anyone help me solve this issue, preferably with pure css. I once found a way to stop this behavior with css, but I do not seem to recall how I did it.

Comment: can you come up with code

Comment: you need to disable the elements, which can't be done with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to use the pointer-events?

disable pointer-events on the popup using `pointer-events: none;` and if you have something clickable, just give it back the ability to be so with `pointer-events: auto;`